# Updating android app Dynamically?

Tags: android, android-update-app

Suppose i have a TextView in my app. I want it to be updated anytime i want to all my app users. How to do that?

I have heard of Microsoft Azure and cloud services. Any tutorial for this? What's the technical term for this thing?

**QUESTION IN DETAIL**

I have a TextView with text - "Hello World". Now i decide to change it to "Good Bye". After some time i change it to "OK FINE". 
Now Everytime user opens my app he should be able to see the updated text or the current text? How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to two parts

1. **Server Part** you subscribe all your users and you send the update as you want.
2. **Client Part**: your android application that subscribe your user in the first use of your app and receive all your updates

To do all this you need to use Google Cloud Messaging GCM, just have a look to [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Good luck!

Comment: unable to understand how this is going to solve my problem. New to android.

My task is to update the ListView with upcoming competitions. How can i do that?

Comment: The tutorial explains one example to use the **GCM** as a push notification but if you don't want to show notification just send a message in your application that send update request to update your `list` because the messages size of push **GCM** is limited by the way it's difficult for a new developer just try to do the exemple of the tutorial then you will have an idea how to use it in other contexts :)